# angular deployment on the apache server

Tags: apache, angular, .htaccess

I followed the steps outlined [here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment).
I copied and paste the code below in .htaccess file. The .htaccess file is in the same repository that contains my dist folder that I am going to deploy on apache.

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

When I access `localhost/dist` everything goes fine, since it will use my index.html file and it will automatically redirect to `localhost/dist/login`. Now if I request directly `localhost/dist/login`, apache complains and displays `The requested URL /dist/login was not found on this server.` It seems for me that apache does not picked up my `.htaccess` settings. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a way to solve my problem. Maybe this could help some. I enabled the `rewrite mode` of Apache and instead of

`RewriteRule ^ /index.html`,

I wrote

`RewriteRule ^ /dist/index.html`

and this solved my problem.